# Formatting with printf linux

Tags: linux, printf, centos7

I have a script below,

```
count=0
max=5
for i in {1..5}
do
sleep 1
count=`expr $count + 1`
printf "%s\r" "$i/$max completed"
done
echo "...OK"
```

The output of above script is below

```
(1 to 5 changing in place)/5 completed. then the line is replaced like "...OKompleted"
```

Output which I want is

```
(1 to 5 changing in place)/5...OK
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

OS: CentOS7

Answer (score 0):

`\r` only puts you at the beginning of the line. If you want to erase the line, you'll need some ANSI escape sequence, or you just use spaces to overwrite those characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
count=0
max=5
for i in {1..5}
  do
    sleep 1
    count=`expr $count + 1`
    echo -en "\\r$i/$max completed"
  done
echo "...OK"
```

Comment: You can see output at the end as: `5/5 completed...OK`

Comment: Please let me know if the solution is helpful !

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider voting up and accepting it if it solved the problem !